# MongoDB: How to use property in find query?

Tags: mongodb

I have user collection:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "514C438232F5699004000014" },
  "gender": 1,
  "loc": {
    "coordinates": [
      0.777084,
      0.701690
    ],
    "type": "Point"
  },
  "name": "H1",
  "radius": 1
},

{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "514C438232F5699004000014" },
  "gender": 1,
  "loc": {
    "coordinates": [
      0.677084,
      0.701690
    ],
    "type": "Point"
  },
  "name": "H2",
  "radius": 0.4
}

db.user.ensureIndex( { loc : "2dsphere" } )
```

I need to write query and use radius property from collection's row ( "radius": 1 ) in find query like this:

```
db.user.find( { loc: { $geoWithin :{ $centerSphere : [ [0.7, 0.7 ] , radius ]}   } } )
```

But mongo returns:

> JavaScript execution failed: ReferenceError: radius is not defined

I have tried `db.user.find( { loc: { $geoWithin :{ $centerSphere : [ [0.7, 0.7 ] , this.radius ]}   } } )`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do a two way query. First fetch the radius of a given user, then search for all location within this radius.